# Java division operator is not giving the expected result

Tags: java, double

I am doing a simple operation of a multiplication and a division in the following manner in Java.

```
100 * 44907280.59 / 44907280.59;
```

I was expecting it to give me 100, but it was giving me 99.999999....

I tried searching Google for the related help, but I could not get any. And if I remove the multiplication part and just divide like below

```
44907280.59 / 44907280.59;
```

the result I see is 1.0

Can someone please explain me what is going on here?

Comment: Use it like this `100 * (44907280.59 / 44907280.59)`

Comment: This is how floating point numbers behave. You should use BigDecimal instead. Please check that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).

Comment: Depends by your number, if you do `100*3.59/3.59`, the result is `100`, but in your case I don't understand.

Comment: @MuratKaragöz, can you pls let me know why there is a difference?